# how to change background-image when the page reloads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Well, iam trying to create a page with diferents backgrounds this is what i did so far.

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    NavBar
  },
  data(){
    return{
      images:[
        {img: '"./assets/img1.jpg"'},
        {img: '"./assets/img2.jpg"'},
        {img: '"./assets/img3.jpg"'},
        {img: '"./assets/img4.jpg"'},
        {img: '"./assets/img5.jpg"'},
        {img: '"./assets/img6.jpg"'},
      ]
    }
  },
  methods:{
    changeBackgroundImage() {

      var item = this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)].img 
      //test 1:
      // document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + item + ")"

      //test 2:
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('./assets/img6.jpg')";

      //test 3:
      // document.body.style.background= 'red'    

    },
  },
  created: function(){
    this.changeBackgroundImage()
  },   
}
```

so, i get a random item on the array, i then put him on the background image right(test 1)?
 but this are not working, so for tests, i try put the path directly (test 2), still not working, no error or message, just... not happen.
So i tried another style command (test 3), just for have sure that this are working, and yah, work normally, letting everything red.

when i go on network, there is a img there, but she is full white, not the one a choose.

So, why are javascript ignoring my background images?

https://github.com/RamonRemo/Projeto1-LembreSee-Front

Comment: When using VueJs you should not manipulate the dom yourself. Check out computed properties and style in their documentation.

Comment: Quick (but probably dirty, not an expert in Vue) fix: https://pastebin.com/ZF5HYVMn

Comment: Kastasx this actually work on the test2, but when i do on test 1 document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${require(item)})`; it doest =(

Comment: For anyone coming here years later, like me, this answer takes care of it beautifully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66925623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a set of quotes in your first test, try like this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + item + "')";
```

Comment: not work =(,
Thats why i was using double quote, i remove them and try your way, but no success