# Giving random background images to each div in the for loop in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, background-image

I have a v-for loop that runs on a div and gives out a bunch of  tags. I need each of those tags to have a different src.  Everything that I have tried so far results in all the  tags getting the same source. Is there any way I can do this?

```html
<div class="wrapper" v-for="result in results" :key="result.index">
         <div class='small-card'>
            <img class="thumbnail" :src="backgroundImage">
            <div class="text-elements">
               <span class="md-display-2 minicard-title">{{result.name}}</span>
               <br class="break">
               <span class="md-display-1 minicard-subtitle">{{result.state}}</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <br class="br3">
      </div>
```

Comment: What you can do is create a function in `methods` that picks a random element from an array which contains all the paths to your images, so it would be something like `:src="selectRandom()"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did this in a project.

What I ended up doing was setting the style tag for `background-image` using the `:style` attribute.

Depending on how you are acquiring the image source, you will need to either create a method to return a random image URL, or access the image URL provided in the object. As you said "random" I assume the first approach would be the best fit.

Here's a very rough and untested example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="index in 10"
      :key="index"
      :style="{'background-image': randomImage()}"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Example',
  data() {
    return {
      images: ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      return `url("${
        this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)]
      }")`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Make sure that the `:style="{'background-image': randomImage()}"` contains a `()` to ensure the method is called vs being referenced.